# How to get the last value in a list/string using Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in writing Python scripts and I need help on the following:

`Threads::num,47141,47146,47151,47156,47161,47166,47171,47176`

How can I get and display the last value '47176'

The following is the part of the code I have written:

```
elif sys.argv[1] == "-c":
    b = sys.argv[2]
    with open(b) as f:
        for line in f:
            if 'Threads::num' in line:
                print line.strip(',').split(',')[-1]
                print line
```

The output of this code is that it displays all the values as follows `Threads::num,47141,47146,47151,47156,47161,47166,47171,47176`

Answer (score 1):

I think your post got re-formatted, because the Python interpreter definitely won't execute it, but take a look at this:

```
print line.strip(',').split(',')[-1] 
print line
```

The phrase `line.strip(',').split(',')[-1]` ends up as '47116', but then you do a `print line` which just outputs the whole of the contents of `line` again.

Comment: is there any problem in the logic ?

Comment: what should I do next Bruce ?